# Anatomical reason why I can’t sit cross-legged?

Tags: yoga

I am a physically fit male who has been a competitive obstacle course racer and weightlifter.  I have recently taken up yoga to improve my flexibility and cannot sit cross legged with a straight back.  My body, especially my lower back strains just to keep me upright. Folds are absolutely impossible. I can round my back and lean over a bit but that’s it. I don’t have any hip problems, squat poses are fine and I have an otherwise strong back. Thinking back, I don’t think I could sit this way as a child either. Has anyone else experienced this issue and identified a cause and treatment?

Comment: It could be because of your knees, are you perhaps slightly knock kneed? See this link where people with knock knees are advised to "avoid sitting cross legged"   https://www.practo.com/consult/knock-knees-can-physiotherapist-suggest-exercises-to-cure-knock-knees-or-alter-a-bit-will-exercising-and-posture/q

Comment: While it's an interesting question, it's not one we can really answer. It could simply be inflexibility, it could be bone structure, it could be form. We just can't say.